# Is it possible to hide or remove a breadcrumb URL in the status bar?

Tags: swift, swift2

For universal links, there are two breadcrumbs: one for going back to the app containing the original link and the other sending the user to the unviversal URL in safari. Is there anyway to hide the forwarding breadcrumb so the user doesn't have the option to click it? The problem i'm facing is, once they hit that URL, when using another universal link in the future, it automatically sends the user to the app store rather than the app itself, despite the app being installed.

Comment: Same issue, it's the default behaviour but it's problematic, users will no longer deep link after pressing that button.

Comment: Yes, I am interested in this question too. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Sasho Have you found any solution?